Optimal lamda in ridge regressioin
Original Ridge paper (Hoerl and Kennard, 1970) proposed the iterative estimation of optimal lambdas (which is k in their notation) in the generalized form of ridge, a form that would yield multiple k's. Has anyone done any research on or read any heuristic estimation for the simplistic form of Ridge (only one k/lambda)?
I know it can be obtained using cross validation, but was interested in some short cuts.

